# Work around for sequelize boolean value from mysql database

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am getting data from `mysql database` to `express` rest api app. Using sequelize as a ORM. 
When it is comes to a `BIT(1)` value from mysql, sequelize returns a `instance of buffer object`.

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "ProductPrice": 12.25,
  "ProductQuantityOnHand": 0,
  "ProductCode": "P486",
  "ProductName": "FirstProduct",
  "ProductDescription": null,
  "ProductActive": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
          1
      ]
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-02-02T11:27:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2019-02-02T11:27:00.000Z"
}
```

Like here product active a BIT(1) and sequelize returning a object.

How can I get `boolean value instead of an object`?

Like this.

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "ProductPrice": 12.25,
  "ProductQuantityOnHand": 0,
  "ProductCode": "P486",
  "ProductName": "FirstProduct",
  "ProductDescription": null,
  "ProductActive": true,
  "createdAt": "2019-02-02T11:27:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2019-02-02T11:27:00.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest that you just use an `INT` column in your MySQL table.  Assuming you only store values 0 and 1, these same values should show up in your ORM/application layer.

As the value `0` is "falsy" in JavaScipt, it would logically behave the same way as `false`, and vice-versa for `1`, which is "truthy."